# Test accuracy and Validation accuracy does not change for my autoencoder

Tags: python, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am trying to make a convolutional autoencoder for color images. I want to reduce the size of the color image from 512,512,3 into a grayscale image of size 256,512,1. Then I want to efficiently reconstruct the image back into its original size and color. To achieve this my model has 2 parts an encoder and a decoder. My problem is when I train my model the accuracy and validation accuracy remains constant at their respective values and never change. Also when I predict the encoded output it not a gray image but a random color image. I am using the following architecture

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import keras, keras.layers as L
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, Adamax
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

def ae(img_shape, code_size):
    H,W,C = img_shape
    
    # encoder
    encoder = keras.models.Sequential()
    encoder.add(L.InputLayer(img_shape))
    encoder.add(L.Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x))) # convert color image to grayscale
    encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    encoder.add(L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    #encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=1, padding='same', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10), activation='relu'))
    encoder.add(L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=1, activation='relu'))
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', strides=2,activation='relu'))
    encoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    encoder.add(L.Flatten())                  # flatten image to vector
 
    encoder.add(L.Reshape((256, 512)))

    # decoder
    decoder = keras.models.Sequential()
    decoder.add(L.InputLayer((code_size)))
    decoder.add(L.Flatten()) 
    decoder.add(L.Reshape((64, 64, 32)))
    decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    decoder.add(BatchNormalization()) 
    decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    decoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    #decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-10), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    
    decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    decoder.add(BatchNormalization())
    decoder.add(L.Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(x))) # convert grayscale image to color
    
    return encoder, decoder
```

I am training the model on the flickr8k dataset but using only 400 images and a batch size of 10 as increasing either of them results in the colab notebook crashing. I have used other optimizers and changed the learning rate also but no success. This shows my accuracy is same and not changing

```
Epoch 1/100
24/24 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2501 - accuracy: 0.4605
Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.44085, saving model to /content/model_hope.h5
24/24 [==============================] - 27s 479ms/step - loss: 1.2501 - accuracy: 0.4605 - val_loss: 0.3070 - val_accuracy: 0.4409
Epoch 2/100
24/24 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2308 - accuracy: 0.4605
Epoch 2: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.44085
24/24 [==============================] - 8s 345ms/step - loss: 1.2308 - accuracy: 0.4605 - val_loss: 0.3528 - val_accuracy: 0.4409
Epoch 3/100
24/24 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.2133 - accuracy: 0.4605
Epoch 3: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.44085
24/24 [==============================] - 9s 392ms/step - loss: 1.2133 - accuracy: 0.4605 - val_loss: 0.3981 - val_accuracy: 0.4409
Epoch 4/100
24/24 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1976 - accuracy: 0.4605
Epoch 4: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.44085
24/24 [==============================] - 8s 346ms/step - loss: 1.1976 - accuracy: 0.4605 - val_loss: 0.4414 - val_accuracy: 0.4409
```

Please if anyone can help me I would be most grateful